# storing data from xml to database using python

Tags: python, xml, django, xml-parsing

1) I need to save the data from xml file to database and display the saved data in UI.

2) I am using mysql for database.

my xml file is

```
<!-- books.xml -->
<catalog>
  <book isbn="1-880985-26-8">
    <title>The Consumer</title>
    <author>M. Gira</author>
  </book>
  <book isbn="0-679775-43-9">
    <title>The Wind-Up Bird Chronicle</title>
    <author>Haruki Murakami</author>
  </book>
  <book isbn="0-679775-13-6">
    <title>Deccon Chronicle</title>
    <author>Kulkarni</author>
  </book>
  <book isbn="0-679775-93-6">
    <title>Python</title>
    <author>David varner</author>
  </book>
</catalog>
```

How to write views.py or filename.py to perform the above operation.I am new to python & xml.Can i get the help from experts.

actually in my bookhandler.py i did this,

```
from sqlalchemy import *
from sqlalchemy.orm import *

import xml.sax.handler

pg_db = create_engine('postgres:///testdb?user=homer')

metadata = MetaData(pg_db)

books_table = Table('books', metadata, autoload=True)

class Book(object):
    pass

mapper(Book, books_table)

class BookHandler(xml.sax.handler.ContentHandler):
    def __init__(self):
        self.buffer = ""
        self.inField = 0
        self.session = create_session(bind=pg_db)

    def startElement(self, name, attributes):
        if name == "book":
            self.isbn = attributes["isbn"]
        elif name == "title":
            self.inField = 1
        elif name == "author":
            self.inField = 1

    def characters(self, data):
        if self.inField:
            self.buffer += data

    def endElement(self, name):
        if name == "book":
            self.session.begin()
            self.newbook = Book()
            self.newbook.isbn = self.isbn
            self.newbook.title = self.title
            self.newbook.author = self.author
            self.session.save(self.newbook)
            self.session.commit()
        elif name == "title":
            self.inField = 0
            self.title = self.buffer
        elif name == "author":
            self.inField = 0
            self.author = self.buffer
        self.buffer = ""
```

my models.py for storing data is

```
class Book(models.Model):
    ISBN=models.AutoField(primary_key=True,unique=True)
    title=models.CharField(max_length=30)
    author=models.CharField(max_length=40)
```

I runned the app,but i am not getting the result.

Comment: take a look at http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html and some MySQL connector for python

Comment: ya sir,i already referred that but in practical i am confused to implement.So a live example will help me more to understand

Comment: @Benjamin what i tried was edited,please see what is wrong with that code

Comment: can i get the answer for the above question

Answer (score 4):

JSON is the answer for database storage on that kind of issue. This probably will work:

https://github.com/hay/xml2json

> python setup.py install

And ready to go:

```
import xml2json
import json

s = '''<?xml version="1.0"?>
<catalog>
  <book isbn="1-880985-26-8">
    <title>The Consumer</title>
    <author>M. Gira</author>
  </book>
  <book isbn="0-679775-43-9">
    <title>The Wind-Up Bird Chronicle</title>
    <author>Haruki Murakami</author>
  </book>
  <book isbn="0-679775-13-6">
    <title>Deccon Chronicle</title>
    <author>Kulkarni</author>
  </book>
  <book isbn="0-679775-93-6">
    <title>Python</title>
    <author>David varner</author>
  </book>
</catalog>'''

### Storage data:
print xml2json.xml2json(s)

### Parsing to use:
json_data = json.loads(xml2json.xml2json(s))
```

Comment: Oswaldo Ferreira just tell me,while doing the above operation wheather we need to make any changes in views.py

Comment: @MonkL You seem to be doing everything right. Are you asking the question specifically for django, in that case i have a feeling you are looking at the idea of writing a management command. You should check this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-management-commands/ which will let you write a shell command. To be able to help you would have to tell what your end goal is though for which you need to write views or filename.py